# NUnit Selenium webdriver is not closed after running all tests

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, atata

I am trying to open browser, run several tests and close browser. My problem is that browser stays open after running all tests. What is the correct way of closing browser? If I put [Setup] and [TearDown] attributes to open and close browser in each test - browser is opened and closed, but if I put [OneTimeSetup] and [OneTimeTearDown] attributes - browser stays opened.

```
using Atata;
using NUnit.Framework;
namespace UITests
{
[TestFixture]
public class UITestFixture
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        //Open Chrome
         AtataContext.Configure().
         ApplyJsonConfig("Atata.json").
         Build();
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        AtataContext.Current?.CleanUp();
    }
}
}

using Atata;
using NUnit.Framework;
namespace UITests
{
class Tests : UITestFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void PositiveTest()
    {
         Go.To<OverallViewPage>().ItemToVerify1.Should.Equal("2,006.59");
    }
    [Test]
    public void NegativeTest()
    {
        Go.To<OverallViewPage>().ItemToVerify2.Should.Equal("2,006.59");
    }

}
}
using Atata;
namespace UITestFixture
{    
    using _ = OverallViewPage;
    public class OverallViewPage : Page<_>
    {
        [FindByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/app-root/pnl/div/div/pnl-total/pnl-total-grid/main-grid/div/div/div/main-grid-row/div[2]/main-grid-row/div[4]/div[3]/div/span")]
        public Link<_> ItemToVerify1 { get; private set; }

        [FindByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/app-root/pnl/div/div/pnl-total/pnl-total-grid/main-grid/div/div/div/main-grid-row/div[2]/main-grid-row/div[4]/div[2]/div/span")]
        public Link<_> ItemToVerify2 { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried to reproduce your issue with latest Atata v1.7.0 and the code similar to yours. I must say that the browser closes after the tests run, so I can't reproduce the issue. May it be that you or me miss some extra specific Atata or NUnit configuration?

Comment: @Yevgeniy Shunevych Hello, thank you for your answer. After your answer I've downloaded solution from https://github.com/atata-framework/atata-samples/tree/master/NetCore3.NUnit and changed Setup/TearDown to OneTimeSetup/OneTimeTearDown and run 1 test. This time browser opened and closed, but page https://demo.atata.io was not opened and I got a message "Cannot build AtataContext as no driver is specified.Use one of "Use*" methods to specify the driver to use,e.g.:AtataContext.Configure().UseChrome().Build()". Did I miss something to put opening/closing browser to OneTimeSetup/OneTimeTearDown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but not correct to use the same `AtataContext` in different tests. Separate `AtataContext` should be created per each UI test, as `AtataContext` also collects log during test execution. But you can reuse the same web driver instance by different tests by passing already created instance of `RemoteWebDriver` to each `AtataContextBuilder`.

Check out the sources of [Fixture Reusing Driver](https://github.com/atata-framework/atata-samples/tree/master/FixtureReusingDriver) Atata sample project.

Basically you need to enhance base test fixture class like below:

```
using Atata;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

namespace AtataSamples.FixtureReusingDriver
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UITestFixture
    {
        protected virtual bool ReuseDriver => false;

        protected RemoteWebDriver PreservedDriver { get; private set; }

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void SetUpFixture()
        {
            if (ReuseDriver)
                PreservedDriver = AtataContext.GlobalConfiguration.BuildingContext.DriverFactoryToUse.Create();
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            AtataContextBuilder contextBuilder = AtataContext.Configure();

            if (ReuseDriver && PreservedDriver != null)
                contextBuilder = contextBuilder.UseDriver(PreservedDriver);

            contextBuilder.Build();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            AtataContext.Current?.CleanUp(!ReuseDriver);
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void TearDownFixture()
        {
            if (PreservedDriver != null)
            {
                PreservedDriver.Dispose();
                PreservedDriver = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in fixture classes where you need to use the same driver instance by all tests enable `ReuseDriver` property:

```
public class SomeTests : UITestFixture
{
    protected override bool ReuseDriver => true;

    [Test]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very mush for help! I needed to open page, perform some clicks and test ~150 values on this page in diferent tests as it is important to verify them separately. I moved [SetUp] to [OneTimeSetup] and [TearDown] to [OneTimeTearown] and solution works as I need it. Thank you once again!